# Qt Parent to delete variable after child has closed

Tags: c++, qt, signals, slot

I'm writing an application in C++ using the Qt library. There is a central window (the parent) and all the children are launched when needed. Since a number of these windows can be open multiple times, but display different data, I'm declaring the objects with `new`. Here is an example of what I've got:

Home_Window.hpp

```cpp
View_Window *SomeWindow;
```

Home_Window.cpp

```cpp
void Home_Window::on_WindowButton_clicked()
{
    SomeWindow = new View_Window();
    SomeWindow->show();
}
```

What I want to do, is delete the object, when the window is closed to reduce the memory footprint of the application. I've already been able to delete all of the objects contained in the child window to reduce memory usage, but the core object still lingers, and if, through a single day a user opens and closes 1000's of windows, and each object holds onto 40-50KB of memory, the footprint of the application goes from a couple of MBs of memory to 100's of MBs of Memory.

I've not been able to find a guide online that would allow me to achieve this. I was considering a slot and signal pair, as I know that when a window is closed, it sends the `QObject::destroyed()` signal. Only issue, is I've not tried to setup a signal and slot pair like this.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to delete the window when it is [closed](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#close), you can set the [`WA_DeleteOnClose`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum) attribute on it. Your `on_WindowButton_clicked()` should look something like:

```
void Home_Window::on_WindowButton_clicked()
{
    View_Window* w= new View_Window();
    w->setAttribute(WA_DeleteOnClose);
    w->show();
}
```

This way, you don't have to worry about destroying `w` yourself, it will get `delete`d automatically when it is closed.

Comment: That is what I setup, but I specified it in the constructor of the View_Window object. After some testing, it appears my worry was for nothing, cause I opened the window a total of about 8 times, memory usage when from 6.2MB to 6.8MB, and whenever I opened the window after that, the memory remained constant. However, for others it's very helpful.

Comment: If that's the case, I'll need to re-write the code just a little bit

Answer (score 1):

You need to do two things:

1. The window's lifetime must be managed even if the window isn't closed.

   You can give it a parent that you know will end its life at some point. Or you can use a `QScopedPointer` or `std::unique_ptr`.
2. The window must delete itself when it's closed.

```
void Home_Window::on_WindowButton_clicked()
{
    //                           parent window flags    
    //                            vvvv  vvvvvvvvvv
    auto window = new View_Window(this, Qt::Dialog);  /* 1. */
    window->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);       /* 2. */
    window->show();
}
```

At the very least, you should set the `Qt::Window` flag. The `Qt::Dialog` includes the `Qt::Window` flag, and also declares the window to be a dialog box - that fact has platform-specific interpretation; read more about window flags [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum).

If your `View_Window`'s API is broken, and it doesn't take the window flags as the 2nd argument to the constructor, you need to set them separately:

```
window->setWindowFlags(Qt::Dialog);
```

Every widget should be taking `Qt::WindowFlags` as the optional, 2nd argument to the constructor, with a default value reflecting the usual use of the window. That's the expectation set by all of Qt's widgets.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to delete the pointer to `ViewWindow` by using: `delete SomeWindow;`